# Allowing Spring to accept requests from any host

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I have a built a spring boot application. I am able to sent HTTP requests to it from local host. However, when I try to sent HTTP requests from any other devices connected to the same wifi network. I get a connection error.

I am running the application through intellij, which serves it using a TomCat server. I was unable to figure out a way to configure the TomCat Server for accepting HTTP requests from any host address.

I have configured CrossOrigin for my controllers as specified below

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What issue are you having? Is there a specific error? Does the request reach your application? Is your firewall accepting connections?

Comment: I am making the HTTP requests with Angular Front End served on a express server. When I make a request from the computer spring is hosted on. There is no issues.

However when I try to make the same request from a different device connected to the same wifi network. I get two errors:

1.  There was an error > XW
2.  Failed to load resources: net::ERR:CONNECTION:REFUSAL

I have tried disabling firewall of the host system but the issue still persists

Comment: What does your configuration classes look like? Better look at the reference document again, https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf